# Error con radio html php css

Tags: php, html, css

Tengo unos cuantos `radio` que se crean dinámicamente con una consulta a la bd, así mismo, también tengo un `select` creado de la misma manera. El problema es que por alguna razón cuando coloco este `select` antes que el `radio`, estos no se activan al dar clic, Sin embargo, cuando comento el `<section class="categ">` donde están los estilos para el `radio` estos sí se activan como siempre.

dejo el código a continuación:

```
<select name="autor" id="autorblog" value="any">
 <option value="elegir" id="elegir">- Elegir -</option>
 <?php
 try {
  require_once('includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php');
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id_autor,nombre,apellido FROM autores');
  $stmt->execute();
  $elementos = $stmt->get_result();
  while ($ele = $elementos->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   foreach ($ele as $autor) { ?>
    <option value="<?=ucwords($autor['nombre']).' '.ucwords($autor['apellido'])?>" id="<?=$autor['id_autor']?>"><?=ucwords($autor['nombre']).' '.ucwords($autor['apellido'])?></option>
   <?php
   }
  } $stmt->close();
 } catch (exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    $stmt->close();
 } ?>
</select>

<!-- <section class="categ"> -->
  <?php
  try {
   require_once('includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php');
   $tipo_blg = "blog";
   $blg = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,subcat FROM subcategorias WHERE tipo=?');
   $blg->bind_param('s',$tipo_blg);
   $blg->execute();
   if ($elementos = $blg->get_result()) {
    while ($ele = $elementos->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     foreach ($ele as $sub_cat) { ?>
      <div>
       <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $sub_cat['id'] ?>" name="subcategorias_blg" value="<?php echo $sub_cat['subcat'] ?>">
       <label for="<?php echo $sub_cat['id'] ?>"><?php echo $sub_cat['subcat'] ?></label>
      </div>  <?php
     }
    }
   } else {
      echo "No hay subcategorías aún.";
   }
   $blg->close();
  } catch (exception $e) {
     $error = $e->getMessage();
  }
 ?>
 <!-- </section> -->
```

Si alguien le ha pasado y me puede explicar porqué sucede, se lo agradecería!

PD: dejo el código css del `radio`:

```css
/* radio-------------------------------------------- */
section.categ input[type="radio"]{
    display: none!important;
}
section.categ input[type="radio"] + label{
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #dbdbdb;
    color: #bcbcbc;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
section.categ input[type="radio"] + label:hover{
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
    color: #083358;
}
section.categ input[type="radio"]:checked + label{
    background-color: #083358;
    color: #eeeeee;
    border: 2px solid #083358;
}
section.categ{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /* justify-content: space-between; */
}
section.categ div:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Es posible que los botones de radio estén tapados por algún elemento transparente. Si lo tienes publicado por alguna parte puedes añadir un link? Me gustaría verlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo el `input` de los `radio` oculto y estos se activan con el `label` con la etiqueta `for` según el `id` de cada elemento. El problema era que el `id` de los `select` era igual al de los `radio` y no seleccionaba nada.

Lo arreglé colocando una identificación aparte al `id`:

```
<option id="<?=$autor['id_autor']."_a"?>"></option>
```